# Best practice on enable/disable webview in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Would like to ask for some advice on what's best way to implement on enabling and disabling the web view on Android?

I have this app wherein it can open urls within (by using web views) which then popups up and covers 80% of the UI, when the user navigates to another page of the app it should hide/close the web view but can be re-opened again when needed.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
    private WebViewInterface webViewInterface = new WebViewInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onOpenURL(String url) {
        navBrowserWV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        navBrowserWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        navBrowserWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        navBrowserWV.loadUrl(url);
    }
};
```

then this is how I close it

```
private void closeWebView() {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "closing webview...");

    // Destroy WebView if it exists
    if (this.navBrowserWV != null) {
        this.navBrowserWV.stopLoading();
        this.navBrowserWV.loadUrl("about:blank");
        this.navBrowserWV.clearHistory();
        this.navBrowserWV.clearCache(true);
        this.navBrowserWV.pauseTimers();
        this.navBrowserWV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that it displays the page properly at first but when I close it and then open the web view again with a url, it does not load the page anymore just a white background (no errors on the logger btw).

Would like to ask for help on how to resolve this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a long time of digging up answers on the internet I found this old post regarding killing Android webview [[link]](http://www.mcseven.me/2011/12/how-to-kill-an-android-webview/comment-page-1/#comment-865).

There's no real way to kill the WebView (it will always run in your process and you can't do anything about it ATM). So you only have to tell the WebView to load a bogus page, for me I did:
`this.navBrowserWV.loadUrl("about:blank");`

**And it works now!**

Quote from the website

```
4.1 .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled() Inhalt
```

Well, you would think that disabling JavaScript in the WebView’s settings would have an instant effect, in short: it does not. Only after reloading the page would there be no javascript any more, and this is not nice by design, since the page is still more or less well rendered.

```
4.2 .stopLoading() Inhalt
```

Since XHR „loads“ something from another server, you might think that calling „webview.stopLoading()“ would have an effect. In short: it does not. Works only on ressources contained within the HTML-file. Pity, is it not… Well, maybe not, since there is no „startLoading()“ method to resume XHR after resuming the activity anyway.

```
4.3 .destroy() Inhalt
```

As a last resort one might think about „destroy()“ing that thing, and true enough, the WebView itself is not accessible after that. Its threads however continue to exist as zombies somewhere in the vast RAM space and also continue to send XHR requests…

```
4.4 .pauseTimers() / resumeTimers() Inhalt
```

In short: Nope, does not work. I even don’t know what these methods are good for if not for controlling JavaScript timers. There aren’t any in plain HTML, AFAIK.

Update: When it comes to timers only, these functions seem to work on 2.3.5 and upwards, however, when there is no timer active at the time of calling the function, all in vain. With my use case: When pausing the app while there is an XHR active (instead of the running timer that schedules the next XHR call), nothing happens and the next timer continues unhindered.

I hope this will help someone who has the same problem as mine.